# TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float

Tags: python, debugging

It's a problem on leetcode. 
You are climbing a stair case. It takes n steps to reach to the top.

Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?

Note: Given n will be a positive integer.
why it shows that?

Show Company Tags
Show Tags

```
class Solution(object):
    def climbStairs(self, n):

        twostairtimes = math.floor(n/2)
        result = 0
        twostairresult = 0

        while (twostairtimes>=0):
            onestairtimes = n - (2 * twostairtimes)
            if onestairtimes == 0:
                result+=1
            elif twostairtimes ==0:
                result+=1
            else:
                result += self.jiecheng(n)/(self.jiecheng(twostairtimes)*self.jiecheng(onestairtimes))
                result += 1
            twostairtimes=twostairtimes-1

        return result

    def jiecheng(self,n):
        c = 1
        for i in range(n+1):
            c  *= i
        return c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `n` is an `integer` cast it like this:

`range(int(n+1))`

Answer (score 0):

Change `twostairtimes = math.floor(n/2)` to `twostairtimes = n//2` or upgrade to
Python 3. CG problem solved